# installing a script in $PATH

Tags: command-line, scripts, bashrc, paths, nodejs

I am trying to use yeoman in Ubuntu.  Everything is installed correctly but I can't use the command `yo` from bash.  If I navigate to the appropriate directory and run `node cli.js` everything works from the command prompt so I think my issue is that the script is not loaded in my `$PATH` variable.

The directory for the script is `/home/qtrain/.node/lib/node_modules/yo` and the actual script is `/home/qtrain/.node/lib/node_modules/yo/cli.js`

I tried to add the path to the .bashrc file using

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.node/lib/node_modules/yo"
```

But when I restart the terminal and type `$PATH`

This is my output:

```
/home/qtrain/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/qtrain/.rvm/bin:/home/qtrain/.rvm/bin:/home/qtrain/.node/lib/node_modules/yo: No such file or directory
```

and obviously yo doesn't work.

My question: Am I not adding the $PATH correctly?  Should I add the directory or the actual script to get this to work in the command line?

Furthermore yo was installed using `sudo npm install -g yo` so it is installed globally.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Also, there is a quote mismatch in the `export` statement.

Comment: On just the point of typing "$PATH" and getting the output you did. The better way to see what the current value of your PATH environment is would be to: `echo $PATH` - posted by Cris Holdorph as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that, even if you add that directory to your PATH, there's no executable program named "yo" there.

I would add a function to your .bashrc:

```
yo() ( cd ~/.node/lib/node_modules/yo && node cli.js "$@" )
```

Comment: @Oli, I uses parentheses on purpose, so the `cd` command executes in a subshell: it will not affect the current shell's PWD.

Comment: Then you'll need to wrap the `(...)` with `{ ...; }`. I get a syntax error if I try this.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's bad form to answer my own question, but, this seems to be a pretty common issue so hopefully this will help others.  Received assistance on irc channel #ubuntu-pa-us.

Solution:

Give file executable permissions.

```
    cd /path/to/directory   
    chmod +x cli.js
```

Create a symlink - must use full path to directory - in my case

```
    ln -s /home/user/.node/lib/node_modules/yo/cli.js /usr/bin/yo
```

Yo now work from command line.

Comment: It's not bad form at all, it's even encouraged: http://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Since it's installed under your home directory, you should add the link as `$HOME/bin/yo` and add `$HOME/bin` to your PATH.

Comment: @glennjackman touche!  Thx Glenn, will do.